# Logging ALL stderr output of crontab to file

Tags: logs, io-redirection, cron

For example, I can log `stderr` of one script in this way:

```
* * * * * run_script.sh > /var/log.txt 2>&1
```

But I want to log `stderr` of all scripts in my crontab. I can append `> /var/log.txt 2>&1` to all scripts, but it's not good if I have hundreds of scripts in `cron`. Is there another, more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

In crontab, you can set MAILTO to point to a mail alias that runs a script.  That script would accept a mail message, strip off the headers and other goop, and log the remainder with logger.  Since all cron script output is sent to the address specified by MAILTO, you'd capture everything.

Example: in crontab

```
MAILTO=myalias
```

In /etc/mail/aliases (assuming you're using sendmail)

```
myalias:"|/usr/local/bin/my-processing-script.sh"
```

and have the script strip off the mail headers and process the cron output.

Comment: can you be more specific about setting up the MAILTO, alias, MTA, script, etc?

Comment: @endolith I've edited the answer to give a basic setup which should work for sendmail and broadly compatible MTAs. You'll have to write the script yourself.

Answer (score 5):

> Any output produced by a command is sent to the user specified in the
>   MAILTO environment variable as set in the crontab(5) file or, if no
>   MAILTO variable is set (or if this is an at(1) or batch(1) job), to the
>   job's owner.  If a command produces no output or if the MAILTO
>   environment variable is set to the empty string, no mail will be sent.

Since it uses local mail, you really don't need to set up anything, or maybe just install mailx if it's not already here. Cron will send you the output, you can save the mail in a file and do many things from there. Trying to modify the way cron works to directly suit your need is not the way to go. If you don't think so, just patch and re-buil cron, call it my_cron and use it instead of cron. And be prepared to eventually keep your my_cron up to date and re-build it often.

Add this at the beginning of all your scripts to log everything and stop at the first error

```
exec 2>&1 > /var/log/YOUR_LOG_FILE
set -e
```

Comment: should the redirection order be the opposite? `> /var/log/YOUR_LOG_FILE 2>&1` i.e., first redirect stdout to a file and only then redirect stderr to stdout (which now points to the file).

Comment: It's pretty crazy that on a minimal server that you need to install a mail service, and possibly a mail client, just to read errors produced by Cron. It feels like an anarchistic design decision.

Comment: ...especially when it's 2021 and there is still no proper solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Ye's script over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7145618/20774 is useful for this as well, though it does both stdout and stderr.

---

> I have a small script cronlog.sh to do this. The script code

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "[`date`] Start executing $1"
$@ 2>&1 | sed -e "s/\(.*\)/[`date`] \1/"
echo "[`date`] End executing $1"
```

> Then you could do

```
cronlog.sh /opt/scripts/sql_fetch >> your_log_file
```

> Example result

```
cronlog.sh echo 'hello world!'

[Mon Aug 22 04:46:03 CDT 2011] Start executing echo
[Mon Aug 22 04:46:03 CDT 2011] helloworld!
[Mon Aug 22 04:46:03 CDT 2011] End executing echo
```