# Logging all crontab output using MAILTO

Tags: linux, shell, cron, sendmail

I've been trying to get all cron job outputs to a file (not email).
The alias is set in /etc/aliases.

`logthecron: "|cronlog.sh"`

And in crontab `MAILTO=logthecron`.
The cronlog.sh file writes to output to some file:

```
#!/bin/sh
$@ 2>&1 | sed -e "s/\(.*\)/[`date`] \1/" >> /tmp/a
```

I am using sendmail. Sendmail uses smrsh, a restricted shell utility that provides the ability to specify, through the /etc/smrsh directory, an explicit list of executable programs available to Sendmail. 
So I symlinked cronlog.sh and sendmail to that directory. Something like...

`ln -s /root/cron/cronlog.sh /etc/smrsh/`

And still keep getting this error.

```
May 10 09:33:11 sandbox01 smrsh: uid 8: attempt to use "cronlog.sh"
May 10 09:33:11 sandbox01 sendmail[23870]: x4ADXB5Y023868: to="|cronlog.sh", ctladdr=<logthecron@[hostname]> (8/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=prog, pri=30787, dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable
May 10 09:33:11 sandbox01 sendmail[23870]: x4ADXB5Y023868: x4ADXB5Y023870: DSN: Service unavailable
```

Note: I am using CentOS v7, the file is executable, email works without issues, tried the entire directory path in the alias and I do not want to write individual cronjob outputs but write all the output of cron jobs to some file.

Reference:

1. smrsh: http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap22sec182.html
2. [Logging ALL stderr output of crontab to file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29759/logging-all-stderr-output-of-crontab-to-file)

Comment: As you can see from your log, cron tries to send an email to `|cronlog.sh`. The value of `MAILTO` will always be taken as an email address.

Comment: I understand that but thats exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want to send the cronjob output to the cronlog.sh file. Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29759/logging-all-stderr-output-of-crontab-to-file

Comment: `/root` is usually only accessible to root, so better to put a copy of the script in `/etc/smrsh`.

Comment: @wurtel - Did that, the error does not change.

Comment: I assume the script has execute permissions for the UID running sendmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use `MAILTO` (which will always be interpreted as an email address), use `SHELL`.

Set `SHELL` to the path of a small executable shell script that runs the given command with output directed to a file:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

now=$(date)
/bin/sh "$@" 2>&1 | awk -v now="$now" '{ printf("[%s]\t%s\n", now, $0) }' >/tmp/cronjob.log
```

The `"$@"` here will be expanded to `-c` followed by the job specification from the crontab file.  It's important to write `"$@"` with the double quotes.

In the crontab, use

```
SHELL=/path/to/cronrun

# rest of crontab below...
```

(assuming `/path/to/cronrun` is the correct path to that short script)